# How to rotate video portrait to landscape

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mpmovieplayer

I am playing video with MPMoviePlayer in my application.
How i rotate video in my iphone landscape to portrait and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

You can't, without using a private API call, but you can synthesize it - you need a pre-rotated video file.

You can also look at playing the video in a UIWebView

For details see this thread http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/2146-can-you-force-movie-play-portrait-mode.html#post125287