# How to get right height when using mpmovieplayer in portrait mode?

Tags: iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller

Can we play a video in portrait mode with changing their height accordingly ?Any way to do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common question here... however

http://iosdevelopertips.com/video/play-movies-in-portrait-mode-with-mpmovieplayercontroller-using-public-apis.html

This shows the steps

There are also clues at
[How to rotate video portrait to landscape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2855149/how-to-rotate-video-portrait-to-landscape)
and
[how to Play movie in portrait mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1423610/how-to-play-movie-in-portrait-mode)

all based around pre-rotating the movie.